# Match "THIS" And Replace with "THAT" RegEx Vb.Net

Tags: regex, vb.net

Trying to find out how to find and replace text with corresponding values.

For Example

1) fedex to FedEx
2) nasa to NASA
3) po box to PO BOX

```
Public Function FindReplace(ByVal s As String) As String

    Dim MatchEval As New MatchEvaluator(AddressOf RegexReplace)

    Dim Pattern As String = "(?<f1>fedex|nasa|po box)"

    Return Regex.Replace(s, Pattern, MatchEval, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

End Function

Public Function RegexReplace(ByVal m As Match) As String
    Select Case LCase(m.Groups("f1").Value)
        Case "fedex"
            Return "FedEx"
        Case "nasa"
            Return "NASA"
        Case "po box"
            Return "PO BOX"
    End Select
End Function
```

The above code is working fine for fixed values but don't know how to use the above code to match added values on run-time like db to Db.

Comment: How are values added at runtime in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by using List and did the performance test against dictionary object suggested by Anton Kedrov both methods takes almost same time to complete but i don't know  the dictionary method will be good or not for longer replacement list because it loop through all the list to find the match entry for replacement.

I thank you all for your suggestion and advice.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)

    lst.Add("NASA")
    lst.Add("FedEx")
    lst.Add("PO BOX")

    MsgBox(FindReplace("this is testing fedex naSa PO box"))
End Sub

Public Function FindReplace(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim Pattern As String = "(?<f1>fedex|nasa|po box)"
    Dim MatchEval As New MatchEvaluator(AddressOf RegexReplace)
    Return Regex.Replace(s, Pattern, MatchEval, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

End Function

Public Function RegexReplace(ByVal m As Match) As String
    Dim Found As String
    Found = lst.Find(Function(value As String) LCase(value) = LCase(m.Groups("f1").Value))
    Return Found
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess, that the only thing here you need Regex for is IgnoreCase option. If so, then I would like to suggest not to use Regex at all. Use String functionality instead:

```
Dim input As String = "fEDeX"
Dim pattern As String = "fedex"
Dim replacement As String = "FedEx"

Dim result As String

result = input.ToLowerInvariant().Replace(pattern, replacement)
```

But if you still need Regex, then this should work:

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Example:

```
Sub Main()
  Dim replacements As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
  replacements.Add("fedex", "FedEx")
  replacements.Add("nasa", "NASA")
  replacements.Add("po box", "PO BOX")

  Dim result As String = Replace("fedex, nAsA, po box, etc", replacements)
End Sub

Private Function Replace(ByVal input As String, ByVal replacements As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As String
  For Each item In replacements
    input = Regex.Replace(input, item.Key, item.Value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
  Next

  Return input
End Function
```

Comment: The only difference between part 1 and part 2 is that part 1 will lower whole input (which, I guess, might be acceptable). The point of part 2 was to show, that there is no need to use MathcEvaluator and named groups.

Comment: but still, because you are not using regexes your replacements may not be preceeded by `"<f1>"`.

Comment: I think that you misunderstand what `"<f1>"` means here - it actually means nothing, it's just a captured group name. And named groups not needed for this particular case.

Comment: @Anton Kedrov Thanks for your suggestion. I use your suggested method and did performance test against list object (please see the code above) both methods takes almost same time to complete but i don't know the dictionary method will be good or not for longer replacement list because it loop through all the list to find the match entry for replacement. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: In foreach loop, Dictionary should be as good as List, unless you get Value by Key (like `pattern = replacements(input)`). `Add()` method might be slower for Dictionary, but you shouldn't worry about it either.